# Can't assing null to next value for reply subject

Tags: angular

I'm new to angular and I'm trying to assign null value for replysubject in angular .
I exactly wrote my code from tutorial but i wonder why i cant assign null value for this kind of object.
Here's my code from my service class.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { User } from '../_models/user';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AccountService {
  baseUrl="https://localhost:5001/api/";
  private currentUserSource=new ReplaySubject<User>(1);
  currentUser$=this.currentUserSource.asObservable();

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {

   }

  login(model: any) {
    return this.http.post<User>(this.baseUrl + 'account/login', model).pipe(
      map((response: User) => {
        const user = response;
        if (user) {
         localStorage.setItem('user',JSON.stringify(user));
         this.currentUserSource.next(user);
        }
      })
    )
  }

  setCurrentUser(user:User){
    this.currentUserSource.next(user);
  }

  logout(){
    localStorage.removeItem('user');
    ****this.currentUserSource.next(null);****   this line won't compile
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The `map` operator must return something. If not it might return `undefined` to the subscribers. You're better off using the `tap` operator here seeing there are no response transformations required.

```js
login(model: any): Observable<User> {
  return this.http.post<User>(this.baseUrl + 'account/login', model).pipe(
    tap((response: User) => {
      const user = response;
      if (user) {
        localStorage.setItem('user',JSON.stringify(user));
        this.currentUserSource.next(user);
      }
    })
  );
}
```

2. About the error, most probably the tutorial was written pre-[Angular Ivy](https://angular.io/guide/ivy). With Ivy AoT enabled, the values pushed must conform to the types defined. In your case you're pushing `null` to observable of type `User`. You could either disable Ivy or use union types to also accept `null`.

```js
private currentUserSource=new ReplaySubject<User | null>(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import { environment } from '@environments/environment';
import { take, Observable, ReplaySubject, tap } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '@app/models/identity/User';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AccountService {
  private currentUserSource = new ReplaySubject<User>(1);
  public currentUser$ = this.currentUserSource.asObservable();

  baseUrl = environment.apiURL + 'api/account/';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }

  public login(model: any): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.post<User>(this.baseUrl + 'login', model).pipe(
      take(1),
      tap((source: User) => {
        const user = source;
        if (user) {
          this.setCurrentUser(user)
        }
      })
    );
  }

  public logout(): void {
    localStorage.removeItem('user');
    this.currentUserSource.next(null as any);
    this.currentUserSource.complete();
  }

  public setCurrentUser(user: User): void {
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
    this.currentUserSource.next(user);
  }
}
```