# ReplaySubject with null value causes page to hang

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am using Angular 13 (whereas the course that I am doing used Angular 12). Based on the research done, I suspect this is where the issue comes in, however I need to figure out how to make my code work on v13.

My account service is as follows:

```
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { take, Observable, tap, ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../_models/user';
import { map } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AccountService {

  baseUrl = environment.apiUrl;

  private currentUserSource = new ReplaySubject<User>(1);
  public currentUser$ = this.currentUserSource.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public login(model: any): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.post<User>(this.baseUrl + 'account/login', model).pipe(
      take(1),
      tap((response: User) => {
        const user = response;
        if (user) {
          this.setCurrentUser(user);
        }
      })
    )
  }

  register(model: any) {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + "account/register", model).pipe(
      map((user: User) => {
        if (user) {

        }
      })
    )
  }

  public setCurrentUser(user: User) : void {
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
    this.currentUserSource.next(user);
  }

  public logout() : void {
    localStorage.removeItem('user');
    this.currentUserSource.next(null as any);
    this.currentUserSource.complete();
  }
}
```

The login functionality works perfectly, but when I call the logout method my browser just hangs.  The problem comes in where I have

```
this.currentUserSource.next(null as any);
```

How do I set my ReplaySubject to null on logout?

My problem is very similar to [Can't assing null to next value for reply subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67264096/cant-assing-null-to-next-value-for-reply-subject) and I tried the code on this page that was submitted by Bruno Salgado, however that does not resolve the problem.

Comment: I don't think it is related to `AccountService`. You need to share who subscribes to `currentUserSource` observable.

Answer (score -2):

Why not reply by empty object

```
this.currentUserSource.next({} as any);
```

Example: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-replaysubject-bvhcns)